# Python/Pandas Set y-axis attribute

Tags: python, pandas

**Code**:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import sys 
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
pl.draw()

df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv")
df = df.set_index(["country"])
df2 = df.loc["Zimbabwe", "e_mort_num"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df2, columns= ["e_mort_num"])
df.columns = ["Mortality"]
print(df2)

dataset = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"],
         'Mortality': ["20000", "18000", "17000", "19000", "19000", "22000", "24000", "24000", "23000", "17000", "13000", "14000","14000", "11000", "11000", "9000","5600"]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset)
df4 = df3[["Year", "Mortality"]]

plt.bar(df3['Year'], df3['Mortality'])
plt.title('Zimbabwe')
plt.xticks(df3['Year'], rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Mortality')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

print(df3)
```

The output is:

[image: Tubercolosis Mortality]

Edit: What I would like to achieve (made from excel):

[image]

**Questions**:

1. How can I make my x-axis or y-axis start from zero?

**Research**:

2. I have looked into the Panda API and I noticed that they have no actual solution for my problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How can I make my x-axis or y-axis start from zero?"

Comment: Hi Sacul, I've just edited my post to highlight what I'm trying to achieve, so basically I want to set the x-axis to zero, and re-arrange the x-axis to be ascending, rather than how it is now being "random".

Comment: In your desired plot, your x axis starts at 2000. Do you mean the y axis?

Comment: Hey Sacul, I just replied to your other post, and I meant y-axis sorry, but you've solved my problem so thanks agian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your dataframe columns `Year` and `Mortality` are strings, and `matplotlib` doesn't work so well with that, at least for what you're trying to achieve. So, convert them to `int` before plotting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df[['Year', 'Mortality']] = df[['Year', 'Mortality']].astype(int)

plt.bar(df['Year'], df['Mortality'], tick_label=df['Year'])
plt.title('Zimbabwe')
plt.xticks(df['Year'], rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Mortality')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

With your given data, the y axis is automatically set to start at 0. However, you can change it to whatever you want with the `ylim` argument: For instance, `plt.ylim(500, 50000)` would set the y axis to start at 500 and end at 50000.

Comment: Hi Sacul, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll be sure to keep that in mind regarding strings, I wasn't aware of it! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem! If my answers are what you're looking for, I'd appreciate it if you accepted them (using the checkmark below the vote counts)!

Comment: Oh right, I wasn't aware of the checkmark. I've been trying to "upvote" but I don't have enough reputation. I'll definitely be doing that in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! (and see my update regarding how to set the y axis range)